# Access component's this inside firebase promise reposonse

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuefire

I've tried to bind it like it doesn't seem to make the  trick :)

```
firebaseInstance.auth().fetchSignInMethodsForEmail(this.signUpData.email)
  .then((response) => {
    ... all logic
  }).bind(this)
```

...since it outputs the following error:
`firebaseInstance.auth(...).fetchSignInMethodsForEmail(...).bind is not a function`

Here is the component's logic, can someone please suggest a proper way to access this after firebase response resolves? :bowing:

```
import { VALIDATION_MESSAGES, VALUES } from './signup.module.config'
import GLOBAL_EVENTS from 'values/events'
import { firebaseInstance } from 'database'

export default {
  name: `SignUpForm`,
  data() {
    return {
      signUpData: {
        email: ``,
        password: ``,
        confirmPassword: ``
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onEmailSignUp() {
      // Here this is component
      console.log(this.$refs)

      firebaseInstance.auth().fetchSignInMethodsForEmail(this.signUpData.email)
        .then((response) => {
            // other logic
          } else {
            // Here this is lost and equals undefined
            this.$refs.email.setCustomValidity(`error`)
          }
        })
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `bind` instruction should be used on a function object, not on a function return value.

By doing

`firebaseInstance.auth().fetchSignInMethodsForEmail(this.signUpData.email)
  .then((response) => {
    ... all logic
  }).bind(this)`

You try to use bind on the return of the `then` method of you promise, which is a promise object and can't use bind.

You can try `firebaseInstance.auth().fetchSignInMethodsForEmail(this.signUpData.email)
  .then(function(response){
    ... all logic
  }.bind(this))`

instead. Here the `bind` is put on the function send in the promise so it should work correctly. I also transformed the function from arrow function to normal, because I think there is no need for arrow function with bind.

Comment: Thank you for the help @Artost I've initially tried the way you suggest it actually returns an error `database__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.firebaseInstance.auth(...).fetchSignInMethodsForEmail(...).then(...).bind is not a function`

Comment: Are you sure you put the bind after the function body, and not after the `then` end parenthesis ? Because in your error, it seems to be after a `)` and not a `}`. If so, it must be a build issue and I'm not sure of the cause.

Answer (score 1):

Using ES8 async/await sugar syntax you can do it like this :

```
async onEmailSignUp () {
    try {
        const response = await firebaseInstance.auth().fetchSignInMethodsForEmail(this.signUpData.email)
        // other logic
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
        this.$refs.email.setCustomValidity(`error`)
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for the suggestion, but for the current logic case it's required to execute logic depending on the response of fetchSignInMethodsForEmail

Comment: I assumed the setCustomValidity was for handling the firebase promise error case. The response of fetchSignInMethodsForEmail is stored in the response variable. You can use it to execute your logic. In either the try or catch bloc, 'this' will refer to the vue's instance. This is why async/await syntax is great, you're no longer bound to the promise's scope.